# Google Maps API Key and a shared IP Address

Tags: wordpress, google-maps, maps

I am on a shared IP address and my maps don't display due to google fair usage policy. Is it possible to force my Wordpress site to use a Google API Key to display the maps rather than being limited through the shared IP address?

Thanka

Comment: When you create a map(by using the maps-javascript-API) the IP is irrelevant, what matters is the domain. The IP is relevant for serverside requests. The reason must be something else.

Comment: From the error it looks like Google's fair useage policy has been exceeded which in turn stops any maps displaying which seems to mean serverside requests

Comment: Which error exactly do you get?

Comment: It states that their use policy has been exceed which means over 2500 requests from the same IP

Comment: This  sounds as if it's related to your IP-address, not to the IP of the server. Can you give a link to the page?

Comment: I don't think that a key will help in this case.

Comment: Really appreciate your help, best